# Verify JWT signature using plain Java

Tags: java

I have some code that generates JWT and tries to verify it.

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.Provider.Service;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.*;  

class Test {
      @Test
      public void testJwt()
          throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, SignatureException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException {
        PrivateKey key = getPrivateKeyFromFile("jwtTest/test_pkcs8.key");
        PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKeyFromFile("jwtTest/test_publickey.crt");
    
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final Map<String, Object> header = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
        header.put("kid", "asdf");
        header.put("typ", "asdf");
        header.put("alg", "asdf");
        final String headerStr =  Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(header));
    
        final Map<String, Object> payload = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
        payload.put("iss", "asdf");
        payload.put("iat", "asdf");
        final String payloadStr = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(payload));
    
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signature.initSign(key);
        signature.update((headerStr + "." + payloadStr).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    
        byte[] signatureBytes = signature.sign();
    
        final String signatureStr = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(signatureBytes);
    
        final String jwt = headerStr + "." + payloadStr + "." + signatureStr;
    
        log.info(String.format("Generated JWT: %s", jwt));
    
        String[] chunks = jwt.split("\\.");
    
        byte[] sigBytes = BaseEncoding.base64Url().omitPadding().decode(chunks[2]);
    
        signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signature.initVerify(publicKey);
    
        signature.update((headerStr + "." + payloadStr).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        Assert.assertTrue(signature.verify(sigBytes));
      }
}
```

The problem is it's return false at the verify method. When verifying, I'm using the public key. When signing, I'm using the private key. I don't see what I could be doing wrong here. Can anyone help?

Here is how I generated the keys:

```
openssl genrsa -out testkp.pem 2048
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -nocrypt -in testkp.pem -out test_pkcs8.key
openssl rsa -in keypair.pem -pubout -out test_publickey.crt
```

Comment: If you are using an update it may not be doing all of the bytes, only a small buffer. Use doFinal rather than update and see if that helps. Also don't set the StandardCharset for getBytes, just use getBytes(); that may be your problem as well.

Comment: There is no doFinal() method on the Signature. Also what is the reason for not setting charset when using getBytes? I have tried it with and with setting it, and it has no effect.

Comment: Sometimes it modifies the char conversion so that when you decode its not the same, since your encoding it from random byte equivalents it can effect it. My final thought for you is that you might want to try generating a public and private key and see if the code works, if it does your keys may not be right.
https://www.novixys.com/blog/how-to-generate-rsa-keys-java/